# Why does Tomcat opens so many Java Processes for my Application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails, jvm

I have a Grails 2.2.4 application which is packed as war and deployed to my tomcat7 server on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit, 8GB RAM.

My setenv.sh file contains the following:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="
-server 
-Xms1G 
-Xmx2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m";
```

I used **htop** to get the number of running processes. I figured out that there are more than 20 running java processes on my system.

Each process of the more than 20 processes looks like this:

```
PRI NI VIRT   RES    SHR S  CPU% MEM* TIME+    Command 
20   0 6028M 1290M 11140 S  0.0 16.2  0:01.21 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file
```

When I stat tomcat with ./bin/startup.sh my application starts without errors. When I access my application with different browsers I get more than 20 Java processes running. The only other Java process I have running is elasticsearch.

1. Why is tomcat starting so many processes for my application?
2. Do I have to limit them? If so how?

Comment: I doubt Tomcat is doing this. Are you executing shutdown before each startup?

Comment: I have started with a clean system. The only other java process running is elastic search.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are probably seeing is threads not processes.  According to `man htop` you can hide user threads interactively using the `H` command.

For the record, Tomcat will create a number of worker threads for processing incoming HTTP requests.  If you (really) need to control the number of worker threads, there are Tomcat configuration options for doing that.